# Can I install kinetic on ubuntu 17

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have Ubuntu ubuntu-17.04 is it possible to install ROS kinetic on it and it will be stable and work probably

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280427/can-i-install-kinetic-on-ubuntu-17/) by [M.gad](https://answers.ros.org/users/33377/m.gad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [REP 3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021) (which defines the target platforms for each ROS Distribution Release):

> **Kinetic Kame (May 2016 - May 2021)**
>
> Required Support for:
>
> - Ubuntu Wily (15.10)
> - Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

So, it's not supported meaning you can't use `apt` to install it on Ubuntu 17 (Zesty). You can, however, install [Lunar Loggerhead on Ubuntu 17 (Zesty)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#lunar-loggerhead-may-2017-may-2019).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-22**:
But its not stable till now and no LTS

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-22**:
That doesn't mean that it's not good or that it shouldn't be used.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-22**:
yeah we can use that but sometimes we get in problem and we cant solve that with our self so its better to use 16.04 with kinetic , its only my opinion Bro